# eclipse gradle Could not run phased build action

Tags: eclipse, gradle, rapidminer

I am trying to run some **gradle** project on windows using eclipse. it is **rapid miner extension template**. but eclipse keeps showing this error:

```
Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.1.1-bin.zip'.
```

com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gradle/api/internal/java/JavaLibrary
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gradle/api/internal/java/JavaLibrary
org/gradle/api/internal/java/JavaLibrary
org.gradle.api.internal.java.JavaLibrary

i tried different gradle versions and different configs. but it keeps showing this error. i need to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

What gradle task did you try to run?

The extension template is used to create new extensions for RapidMiner Studio.

A detailed guide how to use it is found here:
https://docs.rapidminer.com/latest/developers/extensions/

So your first step should be to adapt the *build.gradle* file and then run the   `initializeExtensionProject` task.

Afterwards you can write your Java code to build a new RapidMiner operator for example and then run the `installExtension` task to install the new extension on your local version of RapidMiner Studio.